# Is it possible to change the parent of an element in Vue?

Tags: vue.js

```
    <div id="panels-window" class="block-window" v-if="showPanelsWindow">
        <div v-if="showPanels" id="panels">
            <div id="panel-sorted" class="block-window panel">
                <call-item
                    v-for="(call, index) in callsSorted"
                    v-bind:key="call.id"
                    v-bind:call="call"
                    v-bind:sorted=true
                    v-bind:order="{order: index}"
                    v-on:update-calls="updateCalls"
                ></call-item>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="showOperation"></div>
```

Is it possible to move a one selected call-item element into an showOperation element? That is, I want to remove an element from the list and insert it into another element. Is it possible to do this using Vue?

Comment: Your html seems to be data driven, so I think you can just pull the item out of your callsSorted array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely possible - you will need two lists of elements. The first list will be rendered inside the panels window while the second list of elements will be rendered inside the shown operations container. Something like this:

```html
<template>
  <div id="panels-window" class="block-window" v-if="showPanelsWindow">
    <div v-if="showPanels" id="panels">
      <div id="panel-sorted" class="block-window panel">
        <call-item
            v-for="(call, index) in callsSorted"
            v-bind:key="call.id"
            v-bind:call="call"
            v-bind:sorted=true
            v-bind:order="{order: index}"
            v-on:update-calls="updateCalls"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="showOperation">
    <call-item
        v-for="(call, index) in operationsShown"
        v-bind:key="call.id"
        v-bind:call="call"
        v-bind:sorted=true
        v-bind:order="{order: index}"
        v-on:update-calls="updateCalls"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default
{
  name: 'MyCustomComponent',
  data()
  {
    return {
      callsSorted: [],
      operationsShown: [],
    };
  },
  methods:
  {
    moveCallToOperation(callIndex)
    {
      this.operationsShown.push(this.callsSorted.splice(callIndex, 1)[0]);
    },
  }
};
</script>
```